# React assign dynamic id in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in the state. I am creating a method which adds a new row but how can i assign a dynamic id to the array in the setState?

This is what my state looks like:-

```
myArray: [
 { id:0, title:'Hello', function: 'none' }
    ]
```

And i have a method `addRow` that creates new Array.

```
addRow = () => {
const rows = [...this.state.myArray, {id: '' ,value:'',options: []}];
this.setState({
   myArray: rows
 });
}
```

How can i create a new dynamic id onClick of that method?

Comment: What are the restrictions that the unique id must follow? The simplest solution would just set the id to `array.length + 1`. You could also use a timestamp or you could use the uuid npm package to generate a uuid for you.

Comment: Check out uuid  and nanoid npm packages.

Comment: use uuidv4 package for id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is using length of the current array.

```
addRow = () => {
  const rows = [...this.state.myArray, {id: this.state.myArray.length ,value:'',options: []}];
  this.setState({
    myArray: rows
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches which you can take:

Either add a counter variable `this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })` and increment it on every onClick.

**OR**

Use something like UUID `import uuid from 'uuid'` which will generate a unique id for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can face asyc issues without functional setState, so you can do something like:

```js
addRow = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const { myArray } = previousState
    return { ...previousState, myArray: [ ...myArray, { id: myArray.length } ] }
  });
}
```

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate